# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #54: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView error

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm writing an app that parses both current and planned roadworks info from the web and displays them in a list format. I've created a custom adapter to create and add the list items to the ListView. When I run the app I get a runtime error:

```
Java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{labstuff.gcu.me.org.roadworksscotland/labstuff.gcu.me.org.roadworksscotland.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #54: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                                                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #54: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
                                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
                                                                                                         at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:495)
                                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:862)
                                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                                         at labstuff.gcu.me.org.roadworksscotland.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
                                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Here is my MainActivity class it uses an Async Task to fetch the web info and that's what creates and attached the adapters to the ListViews by calling the attachAdapters() method when complete.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private int currentRoadworksCount;
private int plannedRoadworksCount;
private LinkedList<CurrentRoadwork> currentRoadworks;
private LinkedList<PlannedRoadwork> plannedRoadworks;
private Button currentRoadworksButton;
private Button plannedRoadworksButton;
private ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;
private ListView currentRoadworksList;
private ListView plannedRoadworkdsList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.currentRoadworksButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.currentRoadworksButton);
    currentRoadworksButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    this.plannedRoadworksButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.plannedRoadworksButton);
    plannedRoadworksButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    this.viewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher);
    this.currentRoadworksList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.currentRoadworksList);
    this.plannedRoadworkdsList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.plannedRoadworksList);

    new NetworkAsyncTask().execute();

}

private class NetworkAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    ApiReader reader;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        reader = new ApiReader();
        currentRoadworks = new LinkedList<CurrentRoadwork>();
        plannedRoadworks = new LinkedList<PlannedRoadwork>();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        currentRoadworks = reader.parseCurrentRoadworks();
        Log.e("Progress update", "Current roadworks loaded");
        plannedRoadworks = reader.parsePlannedRoadworks();
        Log.e("Progress update", "Planned roadworks loaded");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        currentRoadworksCount = currentRoadworks.size();
        plannedRoadworksCount = plannedRoadworks.size();

        currentRoadworksButton.setText(currentRoadworksButton.getText().toString()
                + "\n(" + currentRoadworksCount + " Events)");
        plannedRoadworksButton.setText(plannedRoadworksButton.getText().toString()
                + "\n(" + plannedRoadworksCount + " Events)");


        attachAdapters();


    }
}

public void attachAdapters()
{
    RoadworkAdapter currentRoadworkAdapter = new RoadworkAdapter(this, currentRoadworks);
    currentRoadworksList.setAdapter(currentRoadworkAdapter);

    RoadworkAdapter plannedRoadworkAdapter = new RoadworkAdapter(this, plannedRoadworks, "planned");
    plannedRoadworkdsList.setAdapter(plannedRoadworkAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if (v == currentRoadworksButton)
    {
        currentRoadworksButton.setEnabled(false);
        plannedRoadworksButton.setEnabled(true);
        viewSwitcher.showNext();
    }
    else if (v == plannedRoadworksButton)
    {
        currentRoadworksButton.setEnabled(true);
        plannedRoadworksButton.setEnabled(false);
        viewSwitcher.showPrevious();
    }

}
}
```

Here is my adapter class:

```
public class RoadworkAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private LinkedList<CurrentRoadwork> currentRoadworksSource;
    private LinkedList<PlannedRoadwork> plannedRoadworksSource;
    private boolean current;
    private boolean grey;

    public RoadworkAdapter(Context context, LinkedList<CurrentRoadwork> currentRoadworks)
    {
        current = true;
        mContext = context;
        currentRoadworksSource = currentRoadworks;
        plannedRoadworksSource = null;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public RoadworkAdapter (Context context, LinkedList<PlannedRoadwork> plannedRoadworks, String planned)
    {
        current = false;
        mContext = context;
        plannedRoadworksSource = plannedRoadworks;
        currentRoadworksSource = null;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        if (current) return currentRoadworksSource.size();
        else return  plannedRoadworksSource.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        if (current) return currentRoadworksSource.get(position);
        else return plannedRoadworksSource.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null){ rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.current_roadwork, parent,false);}

        if (current)
        {
            if (rowView == null){ rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.current_roadwork, parent,false);}

            TextView titleView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
            TextView date = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_date);
            TextView description = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_description);

            CurrentRoadwork roadwork = (CurrentRoadwork) getItem(position);

            titleView.setText(roadwork.getTitle());
            date.setText(roadwork.getStartDate().toString()
                    + " to " + roadwork.getEndDate().toString());
            description.setText(roadwork.getDescription());

            if (grey)
            {
                rowView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.GhostWhite));
                grey = false;
            }
            else
            {
                grey = true;
            }
            return rowView;
        }
        else
        {
            if (rowView == null){ rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.planned_roadwork, parent,false);}

            TextView titleView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_title_planned);
            TextView date = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_date_planned);
            TextView description = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_description_planned);

            PlannedRoadwork roadwork = (PlannedRoadwork) getItem(position);

            titleView.setText(roadwork.getTitle());
            date.setText(roadwork.getStartDate().toString()
                    + " to " + roadwork.getEndDate().toString());

            String descriptionString = roadwork.getDescription();

            if (roadwork.getTrafficManagement() != null) descriptionString += " " + roadwork.getTrafficManagement();
            if (roadwork.getDiversionInfo() != null) descriptionString += " " + roadwork.getDiversionInfo();
            if (roadwork.getWorksInfo() != null) descriptionString += " " + roadwork.getWorksInfo();

            description.setText(roadwork.getDescription());

            if (grey)
            {
                rowView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.GhostWhite));
                grey = false;
            }
            else
            {
                grey = true;
            }

            return rowView;
        }
    }
}
```

This class can be used for either planned or current roadworks which are slightly different and which one is determined by the boolean "current". Two instances of it are created for each ListView in ActivityMain.
In all other occurrences of this error on SO I can find seem to be because the list item is inflated like

```
rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.planned_roadwork, parent)
```

But mines seem to be coded correctly as

```
rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.planned_roadwork, parent,false)
```

Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Comment: In the `activity_main` layout, it seems that you have some `<View>` inside one of your `<ListView>`s. A `<ListView>` can't have children.

Comment: Yeah that was it, seems I'd left something in there when I first added the ListViews to the layout file, thank you